# Express.js - Less Middleware - Wrong paths generated when using separate folders

Tags: node.js, express, less

I was using the default lessMiddleware setup whereby the **compiled** `.css` files are stored in the same folder as their **source** `.less` files.

I then switched to using separate folders for my `css` and `less` files an d since then the my `.less` files are not being compiled into `.css` anymore (basically the paths are all wrong now - check out the debug log at the bottom). What am I doing wrong ?

**folder structure :**

- .....
- public

  - styles

    - css
    - less
- .....
- app.js

**app.js :**

```
app.use(lessMiddleware(__dirname + '/public/styles/less', {
    force: true,
    dest: __dirname + '/public/styles/css',
    debug: true
}));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) 
{
    res.render('index.ejs');
});
```

**index.ejs :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/css/animations.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/css/global.css"/>
        ........
        ............
```

**Less Debug log :**

```
  pathname : /styles/css/animations.css
  source : /Users/mothership/testapp/public/styles/less/styles/css/animations.less
  destination : /Users/mothership/testapp/public/styles/css/styles/css/animations.css
  pathname : /styles/css/global.css
  source : /Users/mothership/testapp/public/styles/less/styles/css/global.less
  destination : /Users/mothership/testapp/public/styles/css/styles/css/global.css
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution is the following (maybe there's a cleaner one but I couldn't find it) :

```
app.use(lessMiddleware(__dirname + '/public/styles/less', {
    force: true,
    dest: __dirname + '/public',
    debug: true,
    preprocess: {
        path: function(pathname, req) {
          return pathname.replace(/styles\/css\//, '');
        }
      }
}));
```